# How to add another style property to this onClick?

Tags: html, css, onclick

I made this onlick property for my checkbox, my js-fu is like, not there, how can I simply add a border color property as well as bg color?

```
<div id="akseptwrap">    
    <span style="left:-20px; position:relative; top:3px;"><img src="http://euroworker.no/public/upload/1_2_arrow.gif"></span>
    <span id="salgsaksept">
        <input tabindex=12 value="1"  type="checkbox" name="salgsvilkar" ID="Checkbox2" onclick="document.getElementById('salgsaksept').style.backgroundColor='#E5F7C7';" />&nbsp;Salgs- og leveringsvilkår er lest og akseptert
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* keep it in the `onclick` attribute, but it's usually easier to manage broken out into a separate script:

```
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="12" value="1" name="salgsvilkar" id="Checkbox2"/>
    <label for="Checkbox2">Salgs- og leveringsvilkår er lest og akseptert</label>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('Checkbox2').onclick= function() {
        var s= this.parentNode.style;
        s.backgroundColor='#E5F7C7';
        s.border='solid blue 1px;';
    };
</script>
```

I used `this.parentNode` to get the wrapper span around the object being clicked, to remove the need for the extra ID.

Note that since this only detects click, If you click again to unselect the checkbox, the span will still remain highlighted.

Also, don't use XHTML `/>` self-closing format unless you are actually writing an XHTML document. Unquoted attribute values like `tabindex=12` are invalid in XHTML.

re: comment:

> But further, what can I do to revert it if it's unclicked?

To make it easier to handle reverting, I'd go to classes:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight {
        background: #E5F7C7;
        border: solid blue 1px;
    }
</style>

...same markup...

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('Checkbox2').onclick= function() {
        var that= this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.parentNode.className= that.checked? 'highlight' : '';
        }, 0);
    };
</script>
```

Just removing the class when `this` isn't `checked` will reset the style to what it was before, without having to remember the old background and border values.

What's the `setTimeout` for? Well, when the `onclick` event occurs, you've just clicked on the checkbox, and it hasn't toggled its checkedness yet. Indeed, if you `return false` you would prevent the checkbox from being changed at all. So we tell the browser to call us back in a tic, after the default action for the checkbox click has occurred. (Consequently, we have to preserve the value of `this`, which would be shadowed by a new, useless `this` in the timeout function.)

`onclick` is really the wrong event to be using here, it should be `onchange`. However, you will typically see `onclick` used instead because there's a bug in IE where it doesn't fire `onchange` until you unfocus the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, I am using xhtml, copied some previous checkbox code from a project I worked on before. Will remove it. And it's an accept terms box so it only needs to be clicked once. But further, what can I do to revert it if it's unclicked?

Comment: In the function add

    if (this.checked) {
      /* set styles */
    } else {
      /* remove styles */
    }

Comment: That's one amazingly thorough answer, even my non JS enabled mind understands it, thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is focus events.

With IE you will need some javascript (e.g. prototype):

```
document.observe('focusin',function(e){/*set colors here */});
```

With Firefox (and others) you can do it only with css:

```
#Checkbox2:focus {
    /* set colors here */
}
```

Comment: Note `addEventListener` is not supported in IE<=8.

Comment: @bobince true, we can use something like `document.observe('focusin', function() {});`. +1 for that :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
$(this).attr("class","newclass");
});
```

Where you define `.newclass` with new `background-color` and `border`

Or this

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][checked]').click(function(){
 $(this).addClass("newclass"); 
 });
```

Or you can add css manually by replacing $this part with :

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#000");
$(this).css("border", "1px solid #000");
```

There are many ways with jQuery